# Why does pwsh.exe in combination with Start-Process not accept a script block directly?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, start-process, scriptblock, powershell-7.0

Why does `Start-Process powershell.exe { Read-Host }` work, but `Start-Process pwsh.exe { Read-Host }` does not?

I'm aware of the `-ArgumentList` switch of `Start-Process`, but it makes things more complicated when it comes to escaping quotation marks:

PowerShell 7.0.3 and 7.2.0-preview.3:

```
Start-Process pwsh.exe -ArgumentList '-Command "& {
    ''Hello World.''
    Read-Host
}"' -Verb RunAs
```

PowerShell 5.1:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe { 
    'Hello World.'
    Read-Host
} -Verb RunAs
```

---

On the other hand, when creating a new PowerShell session (without `Start-Process`), it is still possible to use a script block:

```
pwsh.exe {
    'Hello World.'
    Read-Host
}
```

Am I missing something here or is there a better/different approach which allows a script block to be executed parallel to the rest of a script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**pwsh** get a filename by default in arguments.
If you try to run it in CMD you will see this:

```
CMD> pwsh { 'Hello!' }
The argument '{' is not recognized as the name of a script file. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Usage: pwsh[.exe] [-Login] [[-File] <filePath> [args]]
                  [-Command { - | <script-block> [-args <arg-array>]
                                | <string> [<CommandParameters>] } ]
(.. other help from pwsh ..)
```

It meant if you want to run some command you must write `-Command { ... }` in arguments.

But you can write more short command for run pwsh like this:

```
Start-Process pwsh.exe '-c', {
    'Hello World.'
    Read-Host
}
```

1. `-c` is shorter equivalent for `-Command`
2. *Script block* will converted to valid string in arguments

Answer (score 5):

You don't show the error message.  Pwsh defaults to -file while powershell defaults to -command.  Running from cmd:

```
pwsh { 'hi there' }
The argument '{' is not recognized as the name of a script file. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

pwsh -command { 'hi there' } 
hi there
```

With start-process -nonewwindow you can see the error:

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow pwsh.exe { Read-Host }

The argument 'Read-Host' is not recognized as the name of a script file. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.

Usage: pwsh[.exe] [-Login] [[-File] <filePath> [args]]
                  [-Command { - | <script-block> [-args <arg-array>]
                                | <string> [<CommandParameters>] } ]
                  [-ConfigurationName <string>] [-CustomPipeName <string>]
                  [-EncodedCommand <Base64EncodedCommand>]
                  [-ExecutionPolicy <ExecutionPolicy>] [-InputFormat {Text | XML}]
                  [-Interactive] [-MTA] [-NoExit] [-NoLogo] [-NonInteractive] [-NoProfile]
                  [-OutputFormat {Text | XML}] [-SettingsFile <filePath>] [-SSHServerMode]
[-STA]
                  [-Version] [-WindowStyle <style>] [-WorkingDirectory <directoryPath>]

       pwsh[.exe] -h | -Help | -? | /?

PowerShell Online Help https://aka.ms/powershell-docs

All parameters are case-insensitive.
```

"pwsh { 'hi there' } works within powershell.  I'm not sure why.

```
.\echoargs { 'hi there' }

Arg 0 is <-encodedCommand>
Arg 1 is <IAAnAGgAaQAgAHQAaABlAHIAZQAnACAA>
Arg 2 is <-inputFormat>
Arg 3 is <xml>
Arg 4 is <-outputFormat>
Arg 5 is <text>
```

It seems to automatically run this?

```
pwsh -encodedCommand IAAnAGgAaQAgAHQAaABlAHIAZQAnACAA -inputFormat xml -outputFormat text
```

Comment: Interestingly, unless I'm using cmd, `pwsh { 'hi there' }` doesn't throw any error for me (tested with PS5 and PS7). Does it for you?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of sending a script block to new pwsh window with start-process (powershell 7)

```
while(1)
{
    $script ={ write-host 'Hello World.' 
    pause
    }
    start-process -Filepath pwsh.exe -ArgumentList "-Command $script"
    pause
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This launches a ScriptBlock in a new window, which is from [groser's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66834860/3767959)

```
Start-Process pwsh.exe -ArgumentList "-c", {
    'Hello World.'
    Read-Host
}, "-noexit" -WindowStyle Maximized
```

The following launch's a script from an open PowerShell window

```
Start-Process pwsh.exe -ArgumentList "-c", ".\Child-Script.ps1", "-noexit" -WindowStyle Maximized
```

This launches a child .ps1 in the same directory as the parent .ps1 script in a new window

**Parent-Script.ps1**

```
Start-Process pwsh.exe -ArgumentList "-c", ("$PSScriptRoot\Child-Script.ps1"), "-noexit" -WindowStyle Maximized
```